# Read log file and print specific input. python

Tags: python, logfile

I am trying to read a log file in order to retrieve the time that the process needs to finish.

I found the below code which works fine:

```
infile = r"C:\DOUBLE\bschfrvNI0870.log"

important = [] keep_phrases = ["real time"]

with open(infile) as f:
    f = f.readlines()

for line in f:
    for phrase in keep_phrases:
        if phrase in line:
            important.append(line)
            break

print(important)
```

However due to the fact that the "real time" keyword is been used a lot of times on the log file. I am thinking to either retrieve

a) the first "real time " key word that finds starting from the bottom of the log file (which is the one that i want)

b) i saw that the "real time" key word that i need is between the below lines

> ---
>
> ### - Process Duration -
>
> ```
>   real time           5:42.72
>   cpu time            5:42.83
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ### - Process Messages -

So Could you please help me modify my code to do a or b

Please let me know your thoughts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: f = f.readlines().reverse() should do the trick - you will be looking from bottom to top and break after the first finding.

Comment: @pkqxdd Sorry for not being clear my Q is how to modify my code to do either a or b.

Comment: @AlexK.thanks Alex i will try it too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the last 'real time' will be the one you want, you could do:

```
print(important[-1])
```

Comment: Thanks ! so true ! I should retreive the last item from my list aka list[-1].